# How ManifoldCF job scheduling behaves?

Tags: search, solr

I am working on integrating manifoldcf or mcf with alfresco cms as repository connector using CMIS query and using solr as output channel where all index are stored. I am able to do it fine & can search documents in solr index.

Now as part of implementation, i am planing to introduce multiple repository such as sharepoint, file systems etc. so now i have three document repositories : alfresco, sharepoint & filesystem. I am planning to have scheduled jobs which run through each of repositories and crawl these at particular intervals. But i have following contentions.

1. Although i am scheduling jobs for frequent intervals, i want to make sure that mcf jobs pick only those content which are either added new or updated say i have 100 docs dring current job run but say 110 at next job run so i only want to run jobs for new 10 docs not entire 110 docs.
2. As there are relatively lesser mcf tutorials available, i have no means to ensure that mcf jobs behaves this way but i assume it is intelligent enough to behave this way but again no proof  to substantiate it.
3. I want to know more about mcf job schedule type : scan every document once/rescan documents directly. Similarly i want to know more about job invocation : complete/minimal. i would be sorry for being a newbie.
4. Also i am considering about doing some custom coding to ensure that only latest/updated docs are eligible for processing but again going thru code only as less documentation available.
5. Is it wise to doc custom coding in this case or mcf provides all these features OOTB.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ManifoldCF schedules the job based on what you have configured for the Job.

1. it depends on how you repository connector is written, usually when when job runs it runs the getDocumentVersion() of repository connector, if the version of a document specification is different that earlier version, manifold indexes that document else not. Usually your document version string is the last modified date of the document
2. Unfortunately, manifold does not contain much of the document from the developer perspective side, your probable bet is to go through the code. It is quite explanatory.
3. This is what minimal is presented as per the mcf documentation

> Using the "minimal" variant of the listed actions will perform the minimum possible amount of work, given the model that the connection type for the job uses. In some cases, this will mean that additions and modifications are indexed, but deletions are not detected [mcf doc jobs](https://manifoldcf.apache.org/release/release-1.9/en_US/end-user-documentation.html#executing)

4. you should implement your logic in public String[] getDocumentVersions(..)
5. OOTB feature, is quite enough. But one thing to consider additionally the permission of the documents. if the permission of the document is changed you can choose change the version of document.